# Display json data using angularJS custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularJS and creating a sample for displaying the json data as mentioned below using angularJS directive:

```
 <div ng-controller="myController">
       <div my-attribute="String1">Hello</div>
       <div my-attribute="String2">Welcome</div>
       <div my-attribute="String3">AngularJS</div>
       <div my-attribute="String4">AngularJS test</div>
       <div my-attribute="String5">AngularJS test 123</div>
 </div>
```

### Actual Response

The directive is displaying last response json data for all the attribute.

```
<div ng-controller="myController" class="ng-scope">
  <!-- ngRepeat: (key, resourceString) in resourceStrings --><ul ng-repeat="(key, resourceString) in resourceStrings" class="ng-scope">
    <div my-attribute="String1" class="ng-binding ng-isolate-scope">AngularJS test 123</div>
  </ul><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, resourceString) in resourceStrings --><ul ng-repeat="(key, resourceString) in resourceStrings" class="ng-scope">
    <div my-attribute="String2" class="ng-binding ng-isolate-scope">AngularJS test 123</div>
  </ul><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, resourceString) in resourceStrings --><ul ng-repeat="(key, resourceString) in resourceStrings" class="ng-scope">
    <div my-attribute="String3" class="ng-binding ng-isolate-scope">AngularJS test 123</div>
  </ul><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, resourceString) in resourceStrings --><ul ng-repeat="(key, resourceString) in resourceStrings" class="ng-scope">
    <div my-attribute="String4" class="ng-binding ng-isolate-scope">AngularJS test 123</div>
  </ul><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, resourceString) in resourceStrings --><ul ng-repeat="(key, resourceString) in resourceStrings" class="ng-scope">
    <div my-attribute="String5" class="ng-binding ng-isolate-scope">AngularJS test 123</div>
  </ul><!-- end ngRepeat: (key, resourceString) in resourceStrings -->
</div>
```

### JSON Response data

{
  "String1": "Hello",
  "String2": "Welcome",
  "String3": "AngularJS",
  "String4": "AngularJS test",
  "String5": "AngularJS test 123"
}

### My script file

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.factory('resourceStrings', function($http) {
var promise = null;

  return function() {
    if (promise) {
      return promise;
    } else {
      promise = $http.get('resource.json');
  return promise;
}
```

};
    });

```
app.controller('myController', function($scope, resourceStrings) {
  resourceStrings().success(function(data) {
  $scope.resourceStrings = data;
```

});
    });

```
app.directive('myAttribute', function() {
  return {
restrict: 'A',
replace: true,
template: '<div>{{displayValue}}</div>',
scope: {
  myAttribute: '=resourceString'
},
controller  : 'myController',
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
  scope.$watch('resourceStrings', function(resourceStrings) {
    angular.forEach(resourceStrings, function(resourceString, key) {
        scope.displayValue = resourceString;
    });
  });
}
```

};
    });

### HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
  <ul ng-repeat="(key, resourceString) in resourceStrings">
    <li my-attribute={{key}}></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

please let me know what was the issue for displaying same data? how to display data as expected?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a plunkr where based on the key, response the value based on the description of your question hope helps.

basically i add a atribute source, because $watch not recognize the data source, see the sample and let me know if it help you. [example - plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/i9raT8PhH0AkpS2onbYv?p=preview)

```
angular.module('myApp', []);
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', ['$scope',
'resourceStrings',
function($scope, resourceStrings) {
   var vm = this;

   vm.example = 'blabla';
   resourceStrings().then(function(value) {
      vm.resourceStrings = value.data;
   });

 }
]);

angular.module('myApp').factory('resourceStrings', function($http) {
  var promise = null;

  return function() {
    if (promise) {
      return promise;
    } else {
      promise = $http.get('resource.json');
      return promise;
    }
  }
});

angular.module('myApp').directive('myAttribute', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div>{{displayValue}}</div>',
    scope: {
      myAttribute: '=',
      source: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.displayValue = scope.source[scope.myAttribute];
    }
  }
});
```